# Calculate SQL AVG using Arel in a has_many association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

I have a model called `Chart`. A Chart has_many `chart_axis_values`. And each `chart_axis_value` belongs_to a Chart and a `chart_axis`.

```
## /models/chart.rb
class Chart < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :chart_axis_values
end

## /models/chart_axis_value.rb
class ChartAxisValue < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :chart
  belongs_to :chart_axis
end
```

`chart_axis_value` has a column named `value` which is a float and of course, as it belongs_to a `chart` and a `chart_axis`, it has columns `chart_axis_id` and `chart_id`.

`chart_axis` has a column named `slug`.

What I want to do is calculate the AVG for `chart_axis_values.value`, but I want to GROUP BY `chart_axis.slug` and i want to calculate it for all Charts (there might be more than 1 Chart).

I thought the SQL query will be something like:

```
SELECT aa.slug, AVG(aav.value) as axis_average
FROM charts c
INNER JOIN chart_axis_values cav
ON cav.id IN c.chart_axis_value_ids
INNER JOIN chart_axes ca
ON ca.id = cav.chart_axis_id
```

And after that, I thought I'll use Arel to use it in my Chart Model, in a method called  'averages',
but i know I'm missing something because I can't get it to work. Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You can select aggregates with `.select('aa.slug', ChartAxisValue.arel_table[:value].avg.as('axis_average'))`. I don't really get where `aa` and `aav` are coming from though.

Comment: @max That was my bad, 'aav' should be 'cav' and 'aa' should be 'ca'. But i see your point,  I'll try and make that work, thanks

Comment: While @max is correct, ActiveRecord already provides methods for this for example `ChartAxisValue.join(:chart_axis).group(ChartAxis.arel_table[:slug]).avg(:value)` this will return a Hash of `{slug => average_value}` given that these are charts I assume this result would be more desirable than a malformed AR object.

Comment: Thank you! @engineersmnky, your suggestion actually lead me to the correct solution and the right way to solve this problem i had. If you want, you can comment belolw so i can credit you with the solution.